# John Resigs Micro Templating vs JQuery Templates or others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resig

I've been using John resigs neat micro templating javascript on a project I'm working on. The project pulls down a JSOn object and spits out a table with a bunch of input fields like so:
[image]

This works ok, however in IE it's slow and locks up the browser for a bit. Works great in Chrome though.

I've looked around the net, and have found a few articles on various templating engines, but they are all getting a bit old now, Jquery templates is a bit new, so I'm wondering, has anyone noticed any performance differences between those and resigs engine? Is it worth me swapping? Or should I give up on JS based templating and just generate server side..?

Comment: I haven't used the micro engine, but I've used jQuery templates a fair bit and I haven't noticed any serious performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

IE, especially the older versions, is slow. If you are noticing a delay then I guess you are dealing with hundreds of objects. I don't think it likely that there is a big enough performance difference between the various templating libraries to provide a solution. Having said that, jquery templates do allow you to compile your templates, which may help.

I don't know about the relative performance but [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) also has a simple templating feature if you don't need anything complicated.